# Erro em um gatilho no Mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

```
create trigger GatilhoRecebimento after insert on recebimentos for each row

begin

    update caixa set valorcréditos_caixa = valorcréditos_caixa + new.valor_receb where caixa.cod_caixa = recebimentos.cod_caixa;

end

$$ delimiter ;
```

Não estou encontrando o erro deste gatilho.

O erro é o seguinte:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6    0.000 sec
```

Comment: Já encontrei o erro. Estava faltando um delimiter no inicio do gatilho.

Comment: Adicione a solução do seu problema como Resposta da Pergunta para poder finalizar o tópico.